# jQuery keydown but ignore if in text box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm calling a function (below) that will perform an action if the user presses the delete button. It is working fine but I need to to only do it on the page and not when a user is typing (inside an input or inside a textarea).

```
$(window).keydown(function (evt) {
    if (evt.which == 46) { // delete
        goDoSomething();
    }
});
```

Any ideas `how I can amend the above` to `not fire` if the user is `in` an `input` or `textarea`?

Thanks in advance,

Dave

Answer (score 15, accepted):

check evt.target's type:

```
$(window).keydown(function (evt) {
    if (evt.target.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'input' &&
        evt.target.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'textarea' && evt.which == 46) { // delete
        goDoSomething();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a global variable and set it to something when a textbox is focussed on and reset it on blur. Something like this:

```
var textboxSelected = false;

$(":input").focus(function () {
     textboxSelected = true;
});
$(":input").blur(function () {
     textboxSelected = false;
});
```

Then in your onKeyDown event check whether the variable is set to false before carrying out the rest of the functionality:

```
$(window).keydown(function (evt) {
if (evt.which == 46 && textboxSelected == false) {

    goDoSomething();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try sometihing like this:

```
$(window).keydown(function (evt) {
  if(evt.target != $('input') && evt.target != $('textarea')){
     if (evt.which == 46) { // delete
        goDoSomething();
     }
  }
});
```